# Convergence criteria of series/sequnces

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

So I have an exercise where I need to show the following statement and I can't find a possible way to prove it, so help would be appreciated.

The  sequence $(a_k)_k$ and $(b_k)_k$ are sequnces of complex or real numbers, with $b_k \neq0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}  $.

Show: If the sequence $\left(\frac{|a_k|}{|b_k|}\right)_k \ $ is convergent, with $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_k}{b_k} > 0 $, then the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k \ $ is absolutely convergent, if and only if the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_k$ is absolutely convergent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex numbers case, the limit should have with the absolute value, if not, saying $>0$ is strange.

Assume $L=\lim_{k}|a_{k}|/|b_{k}|>0$, then there exists some $N$, for all $k\geq N$, $\left|\dfrac{|a_{k}|}{|b_{k}|}-L\right|<1$, then $\dfrac{|a_{k}|}{|b_{k}|}<L+1$, so $|a_{k}|<(L+1)|b_{k}|$, and if $\displaystyle\sum_{k}|b_{k}|<\infty$ then $\displaystyle\sum_{k}|a_{k}|\leq(L+1)\sum_{k}|b_{k}|<\infty$.

Comment: Sorry but I can't follow your prove. Why and how can you say $|a_k|$ < $(L+1)|b_k | \ $? And this this the diretion assmung $b_k$ is absolutely convergent so $a_k$ is absolutely convergent or what is it ?

Comment: Let me fill in more details.

Comment: So I understand the way you prove something but I don't understand why you use $\left|\dfrac{|a_{k}|}{|b_{k}|}-L\right|<1$  how do you come up with it ? It reminds me with the fraction criteria or others for absolute convergence.

Comment: Take $\epsilon_{0}=1$ and run the $\epsilon$-argument to the limit $\lim_{k}|a_{k}|/|b_{k}|$.

Comment: Ok thanks I see, I was just confused why you took a specific epsilon since normaly I used it with any epsilon >0. So I use this prove, for the assumption that the series$a_k$ is absolute convergence too right ?

Comment: Flip over to get $\lim_{k}|b_{k}|/|a_{k}|=1/L>0$, and the proof is exactly the same.